# How to retrieve SVG data from an already loaded asset?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, svg

In my React app I have an svg asset like so:

```
import appIcon from '../assets/dot-to-dot-icon.svg';
```

I want to add the already cached logo to a PDF document, to do so I need to pass the **svg data as a string or xml type** of data to the PDF creation method, but I'm stuck.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import that way then `appIcon` should be the URL of the SVG file.

Once you have that, you can use `fetch()` to fetch the contents of the file.
Something like this:

```
fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(svg => {
     // 'svg' should contain the contents of the svg
  })
```

Comment: What if the asset is already in the DOM? I have tried getElement and getAttribute but I dont know how to access the data, any ideas?

Comment: Fetching should probably be fine as the document should come from the cache anyway.  But otherwise, if you have a reference to a DOM Element node, you should be able to do `element.innerHTML` to get it in string form.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I should mention on my post that the svg was inserted in to an img tag, therefore blocking access to its internals, after I change it to a object tag everything worked.